# Calculating total of values in javascript not giving correct result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I wanted to calculate the sum of them like:

[image]

Snippet not working so i have full implemented code.Yo can directly copy and paste it to check.

```js
         var checkSum=0;
         var sumData  = [];
         //first row total calcualtion
            $(".txt").each(function() {

                $(this).keyup(function(){

                    calculateSum();
                });
            }); 

            function calculateSum() {

                var sum = 0;
                //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
                $(".txt").each(function() {

                    //add only if the value is number
                    if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                        sum += parseFloat(this.value);

                    }

                });
                //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
                $("#sum").html(sum);
                checkSum += sum;
                sumData.push(sum);
            }

            //2nd row calculation
                $(".txt1").each(function() {

                $(this).keyup(function(){

                    calculateSum1();
                });
            }); 

            function calculateSum1() {

                var sum1 = 0;
                //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
                $(".txt1").each(function() {

                    //add only if the value is number
                    if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                        sum1+= parseFloat(this.value);

                    }

                });
                //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
                $("#sum1").html(sum1);
                checkSum += sum1;
                sumData.push(sum1);
            }

            //3rd row calculation
            $(".txt2").each(function() {

                $(this).keyup(function(){

                    calculateSum2();
                });
            }); 

            function calculateSum2() {

                var sum2 = 0;
                //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
                $(".txt2").each(function() {

                    //add only if the value is number
                    if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                        sum2+= parseFloat(this.value);

                    }

                });
                //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
                $("#sum2").html(sum2);
                sumData.push(sum2);
                checkSum += sum2;
                console.log(checkSum);
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <input type="number" class="form-control txt" id="customAmount" name="customReason" min="0">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <input type="number" class="form-control txt" id="customPenalty" name="customPenalty" min="0">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
         <span id="sum">0</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <input type="text" class="form-control txt1" id="vatAmount" name="vatAmount" min="0">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <input type="text" class="form-control txt1" id="vatPenalty" name="vatPenalty" min="0">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
         <span id="sum1">0</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <input type="text" class="form-control txt2" id="exciseAmount" name="exciseAmount" min="0">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <input type="text" class="form-control txt2" id="excisePenalty" name="excisePenalty" min="0">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
         <span id="sum2">3</span>
      </div>                           
   </body>
</html>
```

I tried to put sum in **checkSum** variable but it is showing me such error.And how to decrease the total if the value inside input field is changed or backspace is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are adding your sum to together, you are working off the preview state of the sum, instead you should consider recalculating the sum for all of them anytime a input is changed.

```js
$(".txt,.txt1,.txt2").keyup(calculateSums);
function calculateSums() {
  var names = ["", "1", "2"];
  var sum = 0;
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    sum = 0;
    $(".txt"+names[i]).each(function() {
      if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
        sum += parseFloat(this.value);
      }
    });
    $("#sum"+names[i]).html(sum);
    total += sum;
  }
  console.log(total);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <input type="number" class="form-control txt" id="customAmount" name="customReason" min="0">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <input type="number" class="form-control txt" id="customPenalty" name="customPenalty" min="0">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
         <span id="sum">0</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <input type="text" class="form-control txt1" id="vatAmount" name="vatAmount" min="0">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <input type="text" class="form-control txt1" id="vatPenalty" name="vatPenalty" min="0">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
         <span id="sum1">0</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <input type="text" class="form-control txt2" id="exciseAmount" name="exciseAmount" min="0">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <input type="text" class="form-control txt2" id="excisePenalty" name="excisePenalty" min="0">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
         <span id="sum2">3</span>
      </div>                           
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: AMAZING THNK U SO MUCH :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an incorrect behavior due to wrong design and it has nothing to do with multiple input fields. You can check this by keeping only two input fields and logging the value of `checkSum`.

The root cause is the `checkSum += sum;` line which will keep on the appending the sum of two similar fields (like two inputs with class="txt") every time when an input field from the pair is changed. This is wrong.

To get the correct final total from all the six input fields, you have to remove the lines `checkSum += sum; , checkSum += sum1;, checkSum += sum2;` and call a dedicated function from calculateSum/calculateSum1/calculateSum2 methods which simply adds the value from `sum, sum1 and sum2` spans and returns it.

Answer (score 0):

`checkSum += sum;` isn't working the way you intend it to. If you call it once, you add that value, but the second time you call it, you are adding the ***sum*** of the two inputs instead of the value of the second input.

So if you start with 1, and then in the second box you put 2, your sum is 3, which is fine. But since you already have a 1 in `checkSum`, you are adding `1 + 3`, which isn't what you want.

I know you have already accepted an answer, I just thought you might like to know *why* your code wasn't working the way you intended it to.